# Dynamic data loading is not working in java script

Tags: javascript, html, forms

What I have:

In index.html I have 4 form fields like Annual Salary, Annual Sal Increasement, Present Age, Retirement Age. using ids of those I am validating them in Valid.js
in the time of validating I am set those values in local storage.

//Index.html
 //After Submit

```
    function Validation()
{
//valid.js file using ids of forms 

    var Ann=document.getElementById("Annsal").value;
    var Sal=document.getElementById("SalInc").value;
    var Page=document.getElementById("PreAge").value;
    var Rage=document.getElementById("RetAge").value;
    var Ys=document.getElementById("Yss").value;
    var Nn=document.getElementById("Noo").value;





            // Storing the value above into localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("Asal", Ann);
            localStorage.setItem("Asalinc", Sal);
            localStorage.setItem("Present", Page);
            localStorage.setItem("Retir", Rage);
            localStorage.setItem("Yssss", Ys);
            localStorage.setItem("Nnnn", Nn);


    if(Ann=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="**Please Enter the Annual Salary**";
        return false;

    }
```

Then I take another confirm.html and calculate.js to some do operations on that user entered data then I print in table format in another web page.

//Confirm.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="calculate.js"> 
</script>
</head>    

<body onload="init();">

</body>

</html>
```

Now I am Facing issue in javascript file I retrieve those data using getitem of local storage function.

```
//calculate.js
/ Called on body's `onload` event
    function init() {

        // Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into localStorage

         var a=localStorage.getItem("Asal");
         var b=localStorage.getItem("Asalinc");
         var c=localStorage.getItem("Present");
         var d=localStorage.getItem("Retir");
         var e=localStorage.getItem("Yssss");
         var f=localStorage.getItem("Nnnnn");




        // Writing the value in the document
        document.write("<table><tr><th>Age&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Annual Sal&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>BiWeekly-Pre&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Monthly-Pre&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Cumulative-Pre&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Basic&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Total&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th></tr>")



        for(i=c;i<=101;i++){


            //calculate your formulas here
            // example-- calculating basic salary 

            //use your own formula
            if(i<45)
            {
            basic= salary/2;
            }
            else 
            {
            basic=salary*0.4; 
            }

            //display the content   


        document.write("<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+basic+"</td></tr>")         
        }

        document.write("</table>");

    }
```

But the values are storing but that for loop is not working properly the data is not printing only printing is those table headers why this error can anyone suggest fixing this... Thnx in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked the error console? What errors are you getting? Where are `basic` and `salary` defined and assigned values?

Comment: User enter those values like annual Salary, Annual sal increment, Present Age,Retirement Age ,a,b,c,d,f, those are storing these values only

Comment: #Jon I checked using the alert function in a basic variable its doesn't show any value There is no Error in console But only it Pritning Headers of table

Comment: Just noticed you have variables basic and salary, where do you define those ?

Comment: #noitse I didn't define them directly I'm using in my code

Comment: How are you using those variables. If `basic` is undefined you should be getting a console error: http://jsfiddle.net/uaqk5zhx/ .  What happens if you hard code values for the `a,b ....` variables? Please try to provide us a [MCVE]

Comment: Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/rLkbwxde/2/ . Your init function generates the following error "(index):60 Uncaught ReferenceError: salary is not defined" . Please use your browser tools to check then fix console errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I immediately see is that you have a broken comment:

```
/ Called on body's `onload` event
```

This is near the top of your `calculate.js` file. Make it this:

```
// Called on body's `onload` event
```

And it'll be partially fixed. There are, however, many more errors that you'll find in the JavaScript console.

Comment: I think you'll find there is are more errors that are evident through the console.

Comment: I don't have access to the full code (`index.html` is missing) so I can't check all of it, but I'll check what I can.